# How do I test browser interaction using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

What I mean by my question is this, I have a keypad application that has some JSON data associated with it. An application is written in C# which send the server about the keypad information and it returns with a JSON data. The developer for whom I write the tests, has written some javascript code that represents this JSON data onto the browser screen. My job is to write Jasmine Unit Tests which test, say a function whose job is to load a button on a screen. I can do this spying on the input and output of the function and checking if what I am sending is what I am getting. However, it is not possible to simulate a button click or something similar using Stock Jasmine and Javascript or I don't know how to do it. Since, Jasmine loads up its SpecRunner.html to display its results, I have no way of clicking on the button and look at the result of the test. So basically what the question essentially boils down to is this. How do I modify Jasmine so that I load the application UI first, say click a button, run the tests and check the results after that?

Comment: the keyword is: phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire application screen to load up, then what you are looking for is more of an UI automation test, which is done using tools like `Selenium`.

Instead you can use `fixtures` in `jasmine`, which are essentially small HTML snippets which can either be defined inline as part of the test or as a html file which can be loaded in the `spec`.

The `HTML` goes inside the `fixture`, the javascript is loaded via `SpecRunner.html`, you will just need to call the appropriate methods which bind the events to the rendered fixture in your test.

Further if you to trigger user actions, which would trigger the javascript handlers you can use `jasmine-jquery`. (which also provides fixture functionality)

Check out this: [jasmine-fixture](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture) and [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery)